# How to boot an android TV box from a usb drive containing armbian image

Tags: adb, rom-flashing, fastboot, boot

So I have adb access to my android TV box, the device is rooted.
I want to install armbian onto emmc.
Both official and community tutorial tells me to flash the armbian img onto a usb drive and boot the TV with it.
Is there any way to boot the device from the usb drive?

PS: is `fastboot reboot` the command I am looking for? If so, what pramaters should go afterwards?

Comment: Bootloader that support booting from USB-Stick or SD-card are very rare in Android eco system. Most likely your device boots from internal flash memory and at a certain point recognizes the USB stick and then checks it for update files.